# How to get screen dimensions as pixels in Android

Tags: android, layout, screen, pixel, dimensions

I created some custom elements, and I want to programmatically place them to the upper right corner (`n` pixels from the top edge and `m` pixels from the right edge). Therefore I need to get the screen width and screen height and then set position:

```
int px = screenWidth - m;
int py = screenHeight - n;
```

How do I get `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` in the main Activity?

Comment: Use dp instead of px. because it will distort your layout with other devices..

Comment: Don't forget to multiply by getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density to account for display scaling

Comment: This proves the most up-voted answer is not always the best (& lots of people repeat answers for rep). Instead of getSize and deprecated getWidth/getHeight combo (ignoring errors), try Balaji.K's `getMetrics`. Nik's comment in his answer even explains `getDisplayMetrics` to consider the system/status bar size. Also you may use __density__ as jmaculate and LoungeKatt explained to have the __EXACT__ value:`DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); float fwidth = dm.density * dm.widthPixels;` Tested in Android v2.2 (API 8) and v4.0 with good results and **no errors/warnings**.

Comment: DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

Comment: another way to get the DisplayMetrics : `Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()`. You won't need a `Context` to get them.

Answer (score 3568, accepted):

For **API Level 30**, [`WindowMetrics.getBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowMetrics#getBounds()) is to be used. An example of its usage can be found in the linked docs:

```
 final WindowMetrics metrics = windowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics();
 // Gets all excluding insets
 final WindowInsets windowInsets = metrics.getWindowInsets();
 Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
         | WindowInsets.Type.displayCutout());

 int insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left;
 int insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom;

 // Legacy size that Display#getSize reports
 final Rect bounds = metrics.getBounds();
 final Size legacySize = new Size(bounds.width() - insetsWidth,
         bounds.height() - insetsHeight);
```

---

Old answer:

If you want the display dimensions in pixels you can use [`getSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an `Activity` you can get the default `Display` via `WINDOW_SERVICE`:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

If you are in a fragment and want to acomplish this just use Activity.WindowManager (in Xamarin.Android) or getActivity().getWindowManager() (in java).

Before `getSize` was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

For the use case, you're describing, however, a margin/padding in the layout seems more appropriate.

Another way is: [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as its size, density, and font scaling. To access the DisplayMetrics members, initialize an object like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

We can use `widthPixels` to get information for:

> "The absolute width of the display in pixels."

**Example:**

```
Log.d("ApplicationTagName", "Display width in px is " + metrics.widthPixels);
```

Comment: No way u can do it in the XML?

Comment: @  Abhishek Susarla :
XML usage is general used in a static way you should expect anything to be done dynamically, hope this helps you figure out ur problem.

Comment: well explained MR Mido.  A lot of people who are new to Android don't understand the purpose of the XML files.

Comment: If you use display.getWidth() be sure to set your minSdkVersion to at least 4 in AndroidManifest.xml or you will get incorrect results on some devices.

Comment: Interesting discovery: in the emulator (Android 8) I've specified "Abstracted LCD density" as 150, but when I look at DisplayMetrics.densityDpi it shows 160.

Comment: getWidth() or getSize()?  What would I use if I need my app to run on API <13 as well as API >13?

Comment: try
  {
   display.getSize(size);
   width = size.x;
   height = size.y;
  }
  catch (NoSuchMethodError e)
  {
   width = display.getWidth();
   height = display.getHeight();
  }

Comment: @Arnaud Wouldn't it be a better idea to flip flop the try and catch until getWidth() and getHeight() are actually removed from the SDK? It seems to me your code will end up slowing down devices running API < 13 while giving no speed boost for devices running API >= 13? (BTW Carol, your comment is missing the case API == 13.)

Comment: Good point! I'd bet the majority of devices running API>=13 would less suffer of this than devices running API<13 in terms of performance. Also this would still work until the getWidth is really removed and not just deprecated. Any Android guy to confirm this?

Comment: I don't see why you want to use `try/catch` for such a check? Why not simply use `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13)` without any thrown exception at all? I think of `try/catch` in a normal app-flow as bad practice.

Comment: @CipherCom at least because it might become deprecated as well.

Comment: @A-Live then the app would break as well (but not crashing). We developers must pre-check a new os version nevertheless and this maybe just conceal a problem. Also with this argument one could/should surround every few code lines with try/catch, which in my opinion is bad practice as mentioned already.

Comment: @CipherCom as a developer, you must understand the difference of the general and device dependent code, the latter is always better to use with try/catch at Android world in my opinion. And by try/catch I don't mean spamming exceptions at log but preparing a fallback functionality like using default values.

Comment: @Josef How do the software buttons affect these methods?

Comment: what is 'ctx' in the above code?  Is that a reference to something not defined in the code snippet?

Comment: @WildBill `ctx` is a `Context` variable.

Comment: what if you want to get the screen size excluding the navigation bar and/or notification bar

Comment: If this answer gets you wrong screen sizes, see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078808/android-showing-wrong-screen-resolution) for an extra necessary step.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Navigation, notification and action bars are always the same height, dependent on the system. Check out Android docs to see how many y-pixels

Comment: @milosmns They aren't always being visible. it depends on the device - some tablets have the navigation bar with the notifications inside it (I think on Honeycomb, maybe even later), and also, some devices don't have a navigation bar at all, since they have real buttons

Comment: To handle API Level correctly (Pre/Post API 13) use this code: Point windowSize = new Point();
     Display defaultDisplay = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
     {
      defaultDisplay.getSize(windowSize);
     }
     else
     {
      windowSize.x = defaultDisplay.getWidth();
      windowSize.y = defaultDisplay.getHeight();
     }

Comment: Use getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics) in order to include screen buttons

Comment: You should use the `WindowManager` form `activity.getWindwoManager()`. Else when entering multi window, you will receive the size of your app in full width mode.

Answer (score 123):

It may not answer your question, but it could be useful to know (I was looking for it myself when I came to this question) that if you need a View's dimension but your code is being executed when its layout has not been laid out yet (for example in `onCreate()` ) you can setup a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` with `View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` and put the relevant code that needs the view's dimension there. The listener's callback will be called when the layout will have been laid out.

Comment: or just write view.post

Comment: view.post is not guaranteed to work though. It is just a workaround.

Comment: @marsbear where does it say `View.post()` isn't guaranteed to work? I'm curious because I also rely on this method for getting a View's size after layout and was unaware it unreliable.

Comment: @Turbo I say that :p We used that workaround before and it turned out to be unreliable. That workaround is based on the assumption, that the  initially layouting is done within the same UIThread turn as the initialization. Hence you could schedule your code to run before the next UI turn via post() and be fine. It turned out that the layouting might take even longer under certain circumstances and the view was still not layouted when the posted code ran. What I do now is add the ViewTreeObserver in onCreate and remove it after the first onLayout. Init your stuff during that first onLayout.

Comment: @marsbear does it matter which `View` you get the `ViewTreeObserver` from? Or do they all share the same one?

Comment: @Turbo They should all share the same but the instance you get from getViewTreeObserver might not be valid forever hence you have to check if it is still alive (isAlive()). What I currently do is: getWindow().getDecorView().addOnLayoutChangeListener(). During the first call of the listener I remove it again and call a method in my BaseActivity: afterFirstLayout(). That's where we do calculations that need an initial complete layout cycle

Comment: @marsbear and this method you use always executes at the right time even with the situation you describe about certain views not finishing their layout when View.post() finally executes?

Comment: @Turbo so far: yes. But with all the different custom Androids out there it might fail one day :) The most secure way is to do your work in onLayout within your own View class but that is not always feasible if you want to 'just' put a view off the screen in onCreate for animation purposes.

Answer (score 112):

(2012 answer, may be out of date) If you want to support pre Honeycomb, you will need to put in backward compatibility prior to API 13. Something like:

```
int measuredWidth = 0;
int measuredHeight = 0;
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    Point size = new Point();
    w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    measuredWidth = size.x;
    measuredHeight = size.y;
} else {
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
    measuredWidth = d.getWidth();
    measuredHeight = d.getHeight();
}
```

Of course the deprecated methods will eventually be taken out of the the most recent SDKs, but while we still rely on most of our users having Android 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3, this is what we are left with.

Comment: Yeah, this was back in 2012.

Comment: sorry, allow me to clarify what I meant.  It is highly unlikely that anyone would support API <14 as of 6/22/2015

Answer (score 75):

I have tried all possible "solutions" unsuccessfully and I noticed that Elliott Hughes' "Dalvik Explorer" app always shows correct dimension on any Android device/OS version. I ended up looking at his open source project that can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/enh/

Here's all the relevant code:

```
WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(metrics);
// since SDK_INT = 1;
widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
try {
    // used when 17 > SDK_INT >= 14; includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
    widthPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(d);
    heightPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
try {
    // used when SDK_INT >= 17; includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
    Point realSize = new Point();
    Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
    widthPixels = realSize.x;
    heightPixels = realSize.y;
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

EDIT: slightly improved version (avoid firing exceptions on non-supported OS version):

```
WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(metrics);
// since SDK_INT = 1;
widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
try {
    widthPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth").invoke(d);
    heightPixels = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
try {
    Point realSize = new Point();
    Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
    widthPixels = realSize.x;
    heightPixels = realSize.y;
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

Comment: This is the only post here that takes into account the window decorations (statusbar/menu bar).  worked great for me.

Comment: Awesome, however you should never have expected business logic fire exceptions. Exception firing(even when caught) is horrible for performance. Plus you are doing more work than needed if the SDK_INT is > 13. Instead, you should just add some ifs on the Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.

Comment: @Erik B, I agree. I added improved version. Still I left the part "since SDK 1" just in case something goes wrong in try/catch (I've seen many bad things in Android especially when you think it's impossible something to go wrong so I like to keep it safe :)). Anyway there shouldn't be too mouch overhead since this calculation should be done only once (e.g. values could be kept in some static attributes).

Comment: Note that this code is licensed under GPL v3 which has implications for using in production apps.

Comment: GPL and depending on reflection to call methods which might not be present in future Android versions. Mhhh

Comment: Why reflection, if the function is actually available for API 17 : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point) ? Anyway, this doesn't take into account the current orientation, so it will switch according to it. Here's a solution that will work the same no matter is the orientation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47684256/878126 . However, the question of the thread is about the normal sizes, so it doesn't need the real resolution. Just the part that can be used.

Comment: If using getRealMetricts() you're going to get the full size with windows decorations and these things; just in case someone is wondering how to do this without reflection.

Comment: You're actually using reflection to calculate screen size?

Answer (score 55):

Simplest way:

```
 int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
 int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 48):

For accessing the height of the status bar for Android devices, we prefer a programmatic way to get it:

#### Sample code

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resId > 0) {
    result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
}
```

The variable `result` gives the height in the pixel.

#### For quick access

[image]

For more information about height of `Title bar`, `Navigation bar` and `Content View`, kindly look on *[Android Device Screen Sizes](http://www.emirweb.com/ScreenDeviceStatistics.php)*.

Comment: Just what i needed! `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels + result` gives actual fullscreen height. Dragan Marjanović's answer also works but I prefer this much shorter and simpler solution.

Comment: This approach is outdated as of Android Marshmallow. Status bar height can change from device or Android version. Better use [`OnApplyWindowInsetsListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener.html).

Answer (score 33):

First get view (eg. by `findViewById()`) and then you can use [**getWidth()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getWidth%28%29) on the view itself.

Comment: This is actually how the documentation tells you to do it... but it's kinda pointless if you are NOT using a view. you may be using something else, e.g. mglsurfaceview.

Comment: this is better as the parent view may not be the size of the display. But make sure that this is done at a point where the view you are querying the size of has already been layed out, which will not usually be inside onCreate(). You can use a custom callback from onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) which will be called after all the views have been measured and so on, ensuring you will not receive incorrect dimensions for the view you are interested it...

Answer (score 29):

I have two functions, one for sending the context and the other getting height and width in pixels:

```
public static int getWidth(Context mContext){
    int width=0;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>12){
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
    }
    else{
        width = display.getWidth();  // Deprecated
    }
    return width;
}
```

and

```
public static int getHeight(Context mContext){
    int height=0;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>12){
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        height = size.y;
    }
    else{
        height = display.getHeight();  // Deprecated
    }
    return height;
}
```

Comment: You need to add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` just above the function signature in order to be able to compile.

Comment: I think it's better to get the height and width in one go rather than in separate calls to the APIs because otherwise they could be out of sync. This could happen if the screen orientation is changing while your code is running.

Answer (score 19):

For dynamically scaling using XML there is an attribute called "android:layout_weight"

The below example, modified from synic's response on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581481/assign-width-to-half-available-screen-width-declaratively), shows a button that takes up 75% of the screen (weight = .25) and a text view taking up the remaining 25% of the screen (weight = .75).

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="somebutton">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="Wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 19):

This is the code I use for the task:

```
// `activity` is an instance of Activity class.
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point screen = new Point();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
    display.getSize(screen);
} else {            
    screen.x = display.getWidth();
    screen.y = display.getHeight();
}
```

Seems clean enough and yet, takes care of the deprecation.

Answer (score 19):

Isn't this a much better solution? [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) comes with everything you need and works from API 1.

```
public void getScreenInfo(){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
    widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
    density = metrics.density;
    densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
}
```

You can also get the actual display (including screen decors, such as Status Bar or software navigation bar) using [getRealMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealMetrics%28android.util.DisplayMetrics%29), but this works on 17+ only.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not subtracting space for on-screen controls (such as on Tablets or Nexus devices).

Also, I get a different value (750 vs 800) on my 10" Tablet, depending on whether the Activity is active when the calculation is done. But for my purposes, this is more than fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Just adding to Francesco's answer. The other observer that is more apt, if you want to find out the location in window or location in screen is
[ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html)

This also can be used to find other attributes of a view that is mostly unknown at onCreate() time e.g. the scrolled position, the scaled position.

Answer (score 17):

Find width and height of the screen:

```
width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Using this, we can get the latest and above SDK 13.

```
// New width and height
int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Log.i("", " name == "+ version);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width;
if (version >= 13) {
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    Log.i("width", "if =>" +width);
}
else {
    width = display.getWidth();
    Log.i("width", "else =>" +width);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
DisplayMetrics dimension = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dimension);
int w = dimension.widthPixels;
int h = dimension.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 16):

Using the following code in Activity.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public class AndroidScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        String str_ScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
                                   + dm.widthPixels
                                   + " x "
                                   + dm.heightPixels;

        TextView mScreenSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strScreenSize);
        mScreenSize.setText(str_ScreenSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Need to say, that if you are not in `Activity`, but in `View` (or have variable of `View` type in your scope), there is not need to use `WINDOW_SERVICE`. Then you can use at least two ways.

First:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = yourView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Second:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
yourView.getDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

All this methods we call here is not deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

This is not an answer for the OP, as he wanted the display dimensions in real pixels. I wanted the dimensions in "device-independent-pixels", and putting together answers from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880012/253938 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656774/253938 I came up with this:

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dpHeight = (int)(displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density + 0.5);
    int dpWidth = (int)(displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 14):

For getting the screen dimensions use display metrices

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
if (context != null) 
      WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
      Display defaultDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
      defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
    }
```

Get the height and width in pixels

```
int width  =displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int height =displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 13):

I found this did the trick.

```
Rect dim = new Rect();
getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(dim);
```

Comment: Cool but the is one scary thing about this method in the sourcecode:
[this comment](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/view/View.java#4079)

Answer (score 11):

You can do get the **height** size using :

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

and the **width** size using

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a non-deprecated way to do this using DisplayMetrics (API 1), that avoids the try/catch messiness:

```
 // initialize the DisplayMetrics object
 DisplayMetrics deviceDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

 // populate the DisplayMetrics object with the display characteristics
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(deviceDisplayMetrics);

 // get the width and height
 screenWidth = deviceDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
 screenHeight = deviceDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 10):

I would wrap the getSize code like this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static Point getScreenSize(Activity a) {
    Point size = new Point();
    Display d = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        d.getSize(size);
    } else {
        size.x = d.getWidth();
        size.y = d.getHeight();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: This crashes on a emulator running Android 4.0 (API 14).

Answer (score 9):

For who is searching for *usable screen dimension* without **Status Bar** and **Action Bar** (also thanks to Swapnil's answer):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float screen_w = dm.widthPixels;
float screen_h = dm.heightPixels;

int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resId > 0) {
    screen_h -= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
}

TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
if(getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typedValue, true)){
    screen_h -= getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(typedValue.resourceId);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### Kotlin

```
fun getScreenHeight(activity: Activity): Int {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    return metrics.heightPixels
}

fun getScreenWidth(activity: Activity): Int {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    return metrics.widthPixels
}
```

Comment: Why not use global Resources: `Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels`

Answer (score 7):

First load the XML file and then write this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);      
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final int width = (display.getWidth());
final int height = (display.getHeight());
```

Show width and height according your screen resolution.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the methods below:

```
public static int getWidthScreen(Context context) {
    return getDisplayMetrics(context).widthPixels;
}

public static int getHeightScreen(Context context) {
    return getDisplayMetrics(context).heightPixels;
}

private static DisplayMetrics getDisplayMetrics(Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Much simpler in Kotlin.

```
val displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
displayMetrics.heightPixels
displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

Comment: This one is very short and precise!! Kudos !!

Comment: Watch out - [as others pointed out] this one is only using the static system values, check the source/comments for `Resources.getSystem` if you wanna make sure this one suits your purpose.

Answer (score 6):

There are times when you need to know the precise dimensions of the available space for a layout when in an activity's onCreate.
After some thought I worked out this way of doing it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Measure.class), 1);
        // Return without setting the layout, that will be done in onActivityResult.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Probably can never happen, but just in case.
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        int width = data.getIntExtra("Width", -1);
        // Width is now set to the precise available width, and a layout can now be created.            ...
    }
}

public final class Measure extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Create a LinearLayout with a MeasureFrameLayout in it.
        // Just putting a subclass of LinearLayout in works fine, but to future proof things, I do it this way.
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams matchParent = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        MeasureFrameLayout measureFrameLayout = new MeasureFrameLayout(this);
        measureFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(matchParent);
        linearLayout.addView(measureFrameLayout);
        this.addContentView(linearLayout, matchParent);
        // measureFrameLayout will now request this second activity to finish, sending back the width.
    }

    class MeasureFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
        boolean finished = false;
        public MeasureFrameLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            if (finished) {
                return;
            }
            finished = true;
            // Send the width back as the result.
            Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("Width", MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
            Measure.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            // Tell this activity to finish, so the result is passed back.
            Measure.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to add another activity to the Android manifest, you can do it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static Activity measuringActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            extras = new Bundle();
        }
        int width = extras.getInt("Width", -2);
        if (width == -2) {
            // First time in, just start another copy of this activity.
            extras.putInt("Width", -1);
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).putExtras(extras), 1);
            // Return without setting the layout, that will be done in onActivityResult.
            return;
        }
        if (width == -1) {
            // Second time in, here is where the measurement takes place.
            // Create a LinearLayout with a MeasureFrameLayout in it.
            // Just putting a subclass of LinearLayout in works fine, but to future proof things, I do it this way.
            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(measuringActivity = this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams matchParent = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            MeasureFrameLayout measureFrameLayout = new MeasureFrameLayout(this);
            measureFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(matchParent);
            linearLayout.addView(measureFrameLayout);
            this.addContentView(linearLayout, matchParent);
            // measureFrameLayout will now request this second activity to finish, sending back the width.
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Probably can never happen, but just in case.
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        int width = data.getIntExtra("Width", -3);
        // Width is now set to the precise available width, and a layout can now be created. 
        ...
    }

class MeasureFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    boolean finished = false;
    public MeasureFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (finished) {
            return;
        }
        finished = true;
        // Send the width back as the result.
        Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("Width", MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec));
        MainActivity.measuringActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        // Tell the (second) activity to finish.
        MainActivity.measuringActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you can also pass back the height in the bundle too.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the overhead of WindowManagers, Points, or Displays, you can grab the height and width attributes of the topmost View item in your XML, provided its height and width are set to match_parent. (This is true so long as your layout takes up the entire screen.)

For example, if your XML starts with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/entireLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Then `findViewById(R.id.entireLayout).getWidth()` will return the screen's width and `findViewById(R.id.entireLayout).getHeight()` will return the screen's height.

Answer (score 4):

Above code has been deprecated in API level 30. Now you can get using following code

```
 val width = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds.width()
 val height = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds.height()
```

This method reports the window size including all system bar areas, while `Display#getSize(Point)` reports the area excluding navigation bars and display cutout areas. The value reported by `Display#getSize(Point)` can be obtained by using:

```
 val metrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
 // Gets all excluding insets
 val windowInsets = metrics.windowInsets
 var insets: Insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
 val cutout = windowInsets.displayCutout
 if (cutout != null) {
    val cutoutSafeInsets = Insets.of(cutout.safeInsetLeft, cutout.safeInsetTop, cutout.safeInsetRight, cutout.safeInsetBottom)
    insets = Insets.max(insets, cutoutSafeInsets)
 }

 val insetsWidth = insets.right + insets.left
 val insetsHeight = insets.top + insets.bottom

 // Legacy size that Display#getSize reports
 val legacySize =  Size(metrics.bounds.width() - insetsWidth, metrics.bounds.height() - insetsHeight)
```

Source : [WindowManager#getCurrentWindowMetrics()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowMetrics#getBounds())

Comment: Is there any support library for backward compatibility?

Comment: I think no you will have to use earlier method for API level below 30 and this new method for API level 30 and above

Answer (score 3):

I have a splash screen activity with a LinearLayout as a root view that has *match_parent* for its width & height. This is the code in the `onCreate()` method of that activity. I use these measures in all other activities of the app.

```
int displayWidth = getRawDisplayWidthPreHoneycomb();
int rawDisplayHeight = getRawDisplayHeightPreHoneycomb();
int usableDisplayHeight = rawDisplayHeight - getStatusBarHeight();
pf.setScreenParameters(displayWidth, usableDisplayHeight);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash_view);
    myView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            if (left == 0 && top == 0 && right == 0 && bottom == 0) {
                return;
            }
            int displayWidth = Math.min(right, bottom);
            int usableDisplayHeight = Math.max(right, bottom);
            pf.setScreenParameters(displayWidth, usableDisplayHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

Here are the implementations for the methods you see get called above:

```
private int getRawDisplayWidthPreHoneycomb() {
    WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int widthPixels = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int heightPixels = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    return Math.min(widthPixels, heightPixels);
}

private int getRawDisplayHeightPreHoneycomb() {
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(metrics);

    int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
    int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;

    return Math.max(widthPixels, heightPixels);
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int statusBarHeight = 0;

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }

    return statusBarHeight;
}
```

This results in the height and width of the usable display, excluding any type of bars (status bar, navigation bar), for all API versions and different types of devices (phones and tablets).

Answer (score 2):

Above answer won't work if the Display class will not work then you can get the width and height by below method.

```
private static final int WIDTH_INDEX = 0;
private static final int HEIGHT_INDEX = 1;

    public static int[] getScreenSize(Context context) {
        int[] widthHeight = new int[2];
        widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] = 0;
        widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] = 0;

        try {
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] = size.x;
            widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] = size.y;

            if (!isScreenSizeRetrieved(widthHeight))
            {
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                display.getMetrics(metrics);
                widthHeight[0] = metrics.widthPixels;
                widthHeight[1] = metrics.heightPixels;
            }

            // Last defense. Use deprecated API that was introduced in lower than API 13
            if (!isScreenSizeRetrieved(widthHeight)) {
                widthHeight[0] = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
                widthHeight[1] = display.getHeight(); // deprecated
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return widthHeight;
    }

    private static boolean isScreenSizeRetrieved(int[] widthHeight) {
        return widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] != 0 && widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple function compatible with lower versions as well.**

```
/**
 * @return screen size int[width, height]
 *
 * */
public int[] getScreenSize(){
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        return new int[]{size.x, size.y};
    }else{
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        //noinspection deprecation
        return new int[]{d.getWidth(), d.getHeight()};
    }
}
```

**To use:**

```
int width = getScreenSize()[0];
int height = getScreenSize()[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This function returns the approximate screen size in inches.

```
public double getScreenSize()
{
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width=dm.widthPixels;
        int height=dm.heightPixels;
        int dens=dm.densityDpi;
        double wi=(double)width/(double)dens;
        double hi=(double)height/(double)dens;
        double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
        double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
        return screenInches;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple adaptation from some answers above in a Kotlin implementation. It requires as mentioned above windowsSoftInput="adjustResize" in the manifest:

```
class KeyboardWatcher(private val layoutRooView: View) {

    companion object {
        private const val MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 200f
    }

    private val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics = layoutRooView.resources.displayMetrics
    private var stateVisible = false

    var observer: ((Boolean) -> Unit)? = null

    init {
        layoutRooView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
            val heightDiff = layoutRooView.rootView.height - layoutRooView.height
            if (!stateVisible && heightDiff > dpToPx(MIN_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT)) {
                stateVisible = true
                observer?.invoke(stateVisible)
            } else if(stateVisible) {
                stateVisible = false
                observer?.invoke(stateVisible)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun dpToPx(valueInDp: Float): Float {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
val activityRootView = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.activityRoot)
KeyboardWatcher(activityRootView).observer = { visible ->
    if (visible) do something here ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Created **Kotlin extension** function to get screen width and height -

```
fun Context?.screenWidthInPx(): Int {
    if (this == null) return 0
    val dm = DisplayMetrics()
    val wm = this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    wm.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(dm)
    return dm.widthPixels
}
//comment
fun Context?.screenHeightInPx(): Int {
    if (this == null) return 0
    val dm = DisplayMetrics()
    val wm = this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    wm.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(dm)
    return dm.heightPixels
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is Kotlin extension functions for below/above API 30 code:

```
fun Activity.getScreenWidth(): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        displayMetrics.widthPixels
    } else {
        val metrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
        val insets = metrics.windowInsets
            .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
        metrics.bounds.width() - insets.left - insets.right
    }
}

fun Activity.getScreenHeight(): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        displayMetrics.heightPixels
    } else {
        val metrics = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
        val insets = metrics.windowInsets
            .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
        metrics.bounds.height() - insets.top - insets.bottom
    }
}
```

Corresponding Java helper methods:

```
public int getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    } else {
        WindowMetrics metrics = activity.getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        Insets insets = metrics.getWindowInsets()
                .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
        return metrics.getBounds().width() - insets.left - insets.right;
    }
}


public int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    } else {
        WindowMetrics metrics = activity.getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        Insets insets = metrics.getWindowInsets()
                .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
        return metrics.getBounds().height() - insets.bottom - insets.top;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float fwidth = dm.density * dm.widthPixels;
float fheight = dm.density * dm.heightPixels;
```

If `getSize` gets you an error due to your minSDKVersion and you don't want to use deprecated methods (`getWidth` & `getHeight`), the `getMetrics` solution was originally posted on 2011 by Balaji.K... And Nik added a comment explaining `getDisplayMetrics` also considers the status bar size.

Some other comments refer to multiply by the scale (**density**) in order to get the precise float value of the dimensions. Tested in Android v2.2 (API 8) and v4.0 with good results and **no errors/warnings**.

Answer (score 0):

I used above proposals and created a kotlin version for our question. Hope this provides some additional help for those using kotlin:

```
private val screenDimensions: Int by lazy {
    val display = (context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
    Point()
        .also { size ->
            when {
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 -> display.getRealSize(size)
                else -> display.getSize(size)
            }
        }
}

screenDimensions.x // width
screenDimensions.y // height
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simplest

```
private fun checkDisplayResolution() {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics().also {
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(it)
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "display width: ${displayMetrics.widthPixels}")
    Log.i(TAG, "display height: ${displayMetrics.heightPixels}")
    Log.i(TAG, "display width dpi: ${displayMetrics.xdpi}")
    Log.i(TAG, "display height dpi: ${displayMetrics.ydpi}")
    Log.i(TAG, "display density: ${displayMetrics.density}")
    Log.i(TAG, "display scaled density: ${displayMetrics.scaledDensity}")
}
```

Comment: This seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

### • `Kotlin Version` via `Extension Property`

There are multiple ways of achieving the screen dimensions in android, but I think the best solution could be independent of a `Context` instance, so you can use it everywhere in your code. Here I've provided a solution via kotlin extension property, which makes it easy to know the screen size in pixels as well as `dp`:

#### [DimensionUtils.kt](https://github.com/aminography/CommonUtils/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/aminography/commonutils/DimensionUtils.kt)

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.graphics.Rect
import android.graphics.RectF
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

/**
 * @author aminography
 */

private val displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics by lazy { Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics }

val screenRectPx: Rect
    get() = displayMetrics.run { Rect(0, 0, widthPixels, heightPixels) }

val screenRectDp: RectF
    get() = displayMetrics.run { RectF(0f, 0f, widthPixels.px2dp, heightPixels.px2dp) }

val Number.px2dp: Float
    get() = this.toFloat() / displayMetrics.density

val Number.dp2px: Int
    get() = (this.toFloat() * displayMetrics.density).roundToInt()
```

#### Usage:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val widthPx = screenRectPx.width()
        val heightPx = screenRectPx.height()
        println("[PX] screen width: $widthPx , height: $heightPx")

        val widthDp = screenRectDp.width()
        val heightDp = screenRectDp.height()
        println("[DP] screen width: $widthDp , height: $heightDp")
    }
}
```

#### Result:

When the device is in **`portrait`** orientation:

```
[PX] screen width: 1440 , height: 2392
[DP] screen width: 360.0 , height: 598.0
```

When the device is in **`landscape`** orientation:

```
[PX] screen width: 2392 , height: 1440
[DP] screen width: 598.0 , height: 360.0
```

---

### If you are not a fan of kotlin, use the java version:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

/**
 * @author aminography
 */
public class DimensionUtils {

    private static DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;

    private static DisplayMetrics getDisplayMetrics() {
        if (displayMetrics == null) {
            displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        }
        return displayMetrics;
    }

    public static Rect screenRectPx() {
        return new Rect(0, 0, getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
    }

    public static RectF screenRectDp() {
        return new RectF(0f, 0f, px2dp(getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels), px2dp(getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels));
    }

    public static float px2dp(int value) {
        return value / getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    public static int dp2px(float value) {
        return (int) (value * getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN**

```
fun getScreenHeight(activity: Activity): Int {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    return metrics.heightPixels
}

fun getScreenWidth(activity: Activity): Int {
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
    return metrics.widthPixels
}
```

**JAVA**

```
DisplayMetrics dimension = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dimension);
int w = dimension.widthPixels;
int h = dimension.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a class and a method like below:

```
public MyPoint getScreenDimensionsAsPixel(Context context){
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);

        return new MyPoint(point.x, point.y);
    }

    public class MyPoint{
        private int width;
        private int height;

        public MyPoint(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            return width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            this.width = width;
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
```

and then use them in your codes:

```
MyPoint myPoint = getScreenDimensionsAsPixel(MainActivity.this);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "width: " + String.valueOf(myPoint.getWidth()) + "|" +
                        "height: " + String.valueOf(myPoint.getHeight()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```